# TPMS sensor problem

Tags: mazda, warning-light, mazda-6, tire-pressure-monitoring-system

I have a MAZDA 6 (2010). In general, I do not have any issues with my car. However,  sometimes, I get annoying TPMS warning light. This warning light turns ON very rarely and randomly. Usually, it happens in 3 steps in the middle of the driving-

1. TPMS warning light starts blinking (and continue blinking for a minute or so).
2. Then it becomes solid for a while.
3. Sometimes it automatically disappears after a while but always disappears when I restart the car.

Usually, this happens on a long drive (after driving one hour or so).  I have checked the tire pressure on all wheels, and I did not find any problem.

The main problem is, as this warning light is not consistent, it seems very difficult to Diagnosticate. Is there any way to solve the problem?

Comment: Have you had the TPMS sensors rebuilt?  They have batteries in them which need to be replaced periodically, usually every 3-5 years.  When the batteries get low erratic behavior can be the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sensor's battery is wearing out. Most of the sensors have to be replaced when the battery wears out because they're molded into the case. All the info I've read on them, and my own experience, says they last 8 to 10 years. I've had two that wore out at 9 and two are still going at 11.

The reason it happens on longer trips is because the sensor does not send out a continuous signal but an intermittent one. So the longer you drive, the more you drain the battery.

You'll probably start to see this happen more frequently as time goes on.... sooner or later it will just stay on and you'll have to make the decision to replace it or put up with the warning light.